# Application "org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.E4Application" could not be found in the registry

Tags: eclipse, registry, eclipse-kepler, workbench

I have just moved from 4.2 to 4.3 (kepler). I was working on Eclipse RCP(OSGi framework) which was working fine with 4.2, but once i moved to Kepler- started getting 
below mentioned error while launching. Any kind of help is appreciated.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Application "org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.E4Application" could not be found in the registry. The applications available are: org.eclipse.equinox.app.error.
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.startDefaultApp(EclipseAppContainer.java:248)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.MainApplicationLauncher.run(MainApplicationLauncher.java:29)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1426)
```

Comment: Make sure the plugin `org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench` is included in both your target and your run configurations. See http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseRCP/article.html#runconfiguration_problems

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
open *.product file and then on dependencies tab check "Include optional dependencies when computing required libraries".

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to use the default target:

```
Preferences -> Target Platform 
And check the "Running Platform (Active)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to the workspace folder -> .metadata ->.plugins
Look for the folder matching the name you see in error, in this case - org.eclipse.e4.*

Delete this folder and restart Eclipse. It should open fine now.